# How can I calculate the bending and compression stress on my pawl?

Tags: design

I am working on a project where I am designing a linear ratchet and pawl locking mechanism for a lift. The pawl is going to have to withstand 6000 lb of weight that is going to be transferred by the pin. The bottom of the pawl is going to be in contact with the tracks at an angle which is going to cause it to be in bending and compression. How can I calculate the bending stress? Do I treat it as a beam and use the flexure formula? Also how can I calculate it if I assume the weight is falling 3 in? I have attached the rough idea as  in CAD with rough dimensions. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv0xg.png)][1][image][image]

[image]

Comment: If you think 1 pawl is insufficient, do a redesign with two. You have sufficient length.

Answer (score 0):

### Static case

For the static case, the simplest way to go would be to use FE, since you already have the model ready.

You can also make a simple calculation by analysing the forces. i.e

| Before | After analysis |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Assuming :

- Axis x is the point connecting the contact point to the center of the support.
- the angle $\phi $ is axis x with the horizontal plane.

In that case:

- $F_x = F \sin(\phi)$
- $F_y = F \cos(\phi)$

From that point on the analysis is similar to a cantilever beam with a compressive and shear load. ie:

[image]

The main problem with the above analysis (compared to the FE) is the aspect ratio because the beam is very short, and so you might need to consider other approximation.

### Falling Weight by 3 in.

This is more difficult, because the actual force can depend on many **dynamic** factors that would affect the magnitude of the force. The easiest and relatively safe method would be to multiply the falling weight by a safety factor of 3 or higher (actually for lifting machines this safety factor can go up to 10), and repeat the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I had answered this same question earlier but the diagram was confusing.

Your pawl is not acting as a cantilever beam, it acts approximately as an inclined post and in the static load case it has to support the axial force of

$$F=6000lb /sin(\theta)$$

In the dynamic case, the force it is subjected to is directly related to how much your gear settles by the impact of the pawl before it stops.

Just as an estimate let's say the gear settles $\delta=4mm $ to come to stop.

We can equate the potential energy with the work done by deflection of the gear ( the bearing will deform too but we'll ignore it).

$$ E_{poteisial}= F* \delta \\ F=mgh/\delta \quad 6000*9.8m/s^2*0.0762m=F*4mm\quad F=1,117,200lbs$$

Roughly 1.2 million pounds-force.

As we see this is larger by orders of magnitude (150 times) than the static load. just a precaution to have some sense of what is the difference!
Usually in machinsery desighn the provide recoil mechanism in similar cases to increas the displacement under the impact.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering again. I reposted it because I realized my initial question was confusing. So with that high load of it falling, that would mean this pawl would break due to the impact loading? If the track is permanently deformed, it is okay as long as it still stops it from falling.

Comment: I think you need to redesign the shaft, the bearings, the pawl, and the pawl housing. I would imagine you could attach the gear to a shock absorber and a suspension and recalculate everything. I would recommend you start with 4 pals each twice as big, Remember the impact as it is could passibly smash the entire machine.